# How to add scope to managed rule with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to define scope in Terraform. I can launch managed rule without scope, it works. But when I am trying to define scope got some error:

> Inappropriate value for attribute "compliance_resource_types": set of string
> required.

Maybe someone can help to write the scope correctly?

Here is the code for scope :

```
scope {
  compliance_resource_types = "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand? You need to provide a *set* of strings, not just a single string,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/config_config_rule) states for `compliance_resource_types` of resource `aws_config_config_rule`:

> A list of resource types of only those AWS resources that you want to trigger an evaluation for the rule. e.g. AWS::EC2::Instance. You can only specify one type if you also specify a resource ID for compliance_resource_id. See relevant part of AWS Docs for available types.

You are using a single *string* instead of a list of *strings*.

The following change should fix your issue:

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...
  
  scope {
    compliance_resource_types = ["AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"]
  }
}
```